# insert to orientdb is very slow using ODatabaseDocumentTx

Tags: save, orientdb

I am using [`ODatabaseDocumentTx`](http://orientdb.com/javadoc/latest/com/orientechnologies/orient/core/db/document/ODatabaseDocumentTx.html) to create database in Java.

For each combination of particular key (employee) I am creating class using 
OClass and saving to DB.

```
public void createClassIfNeeded(String className)
{
    OClass oClass = oSchema1.get().getOrCreateClass(className);
    oClass.createProperty("key", OType.STRING);
    oClass.createProperty("ket select", OType.STRING);
    oClass.createProperty("employee", OType.STRING);

    oSchema1.get().save();
}
```

Log

```
18:09:29    DB Open EMP_1
18:09:40    Creating class/indexes for: Data_EMP1
18:10:03    Creating class/indexes for: Data_EMP2
18:13:58    row 1000: 
18:14:02    row 2000: 
18:14:06    row 3000: 
18:14:08    row 4000: 
18:14:11    row 5000:
18:14:11    saved 5000 rows
```

It clearly shows that to save 5000 records its taking ~5 minutes. There are other thread that's running parallel. (5 thread).

Can someone help here?

I am using Solaris and the box has enough capacity. The server health is always good in terms of free memory and CPU.
JVM is assigned 8 GBs.

We get quite better performance with same code in test server which is similar. In Prod there are other application running in that server but I don't think that's having any role as server health is good, only issue we found in saving to OrientDB.

Comment: Are you using remote connection, right? In this case, group your insert in batches by using transaction of, let's say, 1000 items per transaction.

Comment: No, we are creating noSQL DB on JVM label local to application server. Store data only for temporary to consolidate all records and to calculate some price after getting all data & then truncate the DB.

Comment: any idea ...if anyone can help...

Comment: OrientDB with plocal can do more than 100k insert/sec, so there must be something else. Are you doing any lookup to prevent duplication? If yes, are you using an index?